# cannot accept the name from user input and the file does not enter the image directory located in the scanner directory App

Tags: python, django, web

So this program runs smoothly status code 200 and Developer Status does not show error code, I have checked in the models, views, and forms files but the logic of running the system I think is correct. I really appreciate all the help. I alrd try debug from this project [Links](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/imagefield-django-forms/)
scanner.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Scanner</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <style>
      body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        min-height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
      }
  
      main {
        flex: 1;
        padding: 20px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar bg-primary-subtle navbar-expand-lg border border-black">
      <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-evenly">
        <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-python fa-2xl pt-0"></i>
          <p class="fw-bold fs-4 pt-2">Tubes Citra Digital</p>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-flex align-items-start">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item ">
              <a class="icon-link icon-link-hover link-offset-2 link-offset-3-hover link-underline link-underline-opacity-0 link-underline-opacity-75-hover" style="--bs-icon-link-transform: translate3d(0, -.125rem, 0);" href="{% url 'home:home_page' %}">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket bi" aria-hidden="true"><use xlink:href="#clipboard"></use></i>
                Home
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main>
      <!-- From file-->
      <!-- {% url 'cartoon:cartoon_result' %}, Ubah action disini menjadi app dan urls pada setiap APP-->
      <form
        id="cartoon-form"
        action="{% url 'scanner:scanner_page' %}"
        method="post"
        class="validate container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center flex-column gap-3"
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
      >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p class="fs-1 fw-bold text-center">Scanner document:</p>

        <!-- Title image  input-->
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <span class="input-group-text border-primary fs-3 fw-semibold" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa-solid fa-images"></i></span>
          <input name="title" type="text" class="form-control border-primary fs-3 fw-semibold" placeholder="Title image" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        </div>
        

        <!--  File image input-->
        <div class="input-group">
          <input name="image_upload" type="file" class="form-control border-primary fs-3 fw-semibold" id="inputGroupFile02">
          <label class="input-group-text border-primary fs-3 fw-semibold" for="inputGroupFile02">Upload</label>
        </div>
        <button
          class="btn btn-outline-primary mx-auto"
          type="submit"
        >
          Convert
        </button>
      </form>

      <!-- Display Hasil cartoon -->
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="cartoon-result-container">
            <img
              id="cartoon-result"
              alt="Cartoon Result"
              src=""
            />
            {% if error_message %}
            <p>{{ error_message }}</p>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>



      <!-- Copyright -->
      <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(28, 27, 27, 0.05);">
        © 2023 Copyright:
        <a class="text-body" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIcSWuKMwOw" target="_blank">Click this link.</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Copyright -->
    </footer>

    <!-- Script CDN-->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/adc08351c2.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

File forms.p:

```
# scanner/forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import ScannerImage

class ScannerImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ScannerImage
        fields = ['title', 'image_upload']
```

models.py:

```
# scanner/models.py

from django.db import models

def scanner_image_upload_path(instance, filename):
    # instance adalah instance dari model ScannerImage
    # filename adalah nama file yang diunggah

    # Menggunakan title dari instance sebagai bagian dari nama file
    title = instance.title
    # Mengganti spasi dengan garis bawah dan memastikan nama unik
    title = title.replace(" ", "_").lower()
    
    # Membangun path penyimpanan
    return f"scanner/image/bahan/{title}_{filename}"

class ScannerImage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image_upload = models.ImageField(upload_to=scanner_image_upload_path, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py:

```
# scanner/views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ScannerImageForm
import os

def scanner(request):
    return render(request, 'scanner.html')

def save_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ScannerImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Ambil data dari formulir
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            image_upload = request.FILES['image_upload']

            # Tentukan direktori penyimpanan
            save_directory = os.path.join('scanner', 'image', 'bahan')

            # Pastikan direktori tersedia, jika tidak, buat direktori
            os.makedirs(save_directory, exist_ok=True)

            # Simpan data ke dalam direktori tanpa menyimpan di database
            save_path = os.path.join(save_directory, f"{title}.jpg")  
            with open(save_path, 'wb+') as destination:
                for chunk in image_upload.chunks():
                    destination.write(chunk)

            # Redirect atau lakukan hal lain yang sesuai
            return redirect('scanner.html')  
    else:
        form = ScannerImageForm()

    return render(request, 'scanner.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import scanner, save_image
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

app_name = 'scanner'

# URLConf
urlpatterns = [
  path('scanner/', scanner, name='scanner_page'),
  path('result/', save_image, name="scanner_result")
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

All the files are in the App's scanner. This a bit confusing since it's my first time learning Django

Answer (score 0):

Following issues might be causing the problem.

- In your Html file (form tag), the action attribute is set to the URL of scanner `page` but in your `urls.py` the path is set to `result/`. It should be like:

```
action="{% url 'scanner:scanner_result' %}"
```

This change ensures that when a user submits the form, the data will be sent to the correct URL ('result/') where your save_image view function is responsible for handling the image-saving process.

- In your views.py, you are saving the image with the extension ".jpg" regardless of its actual file type. It's better to use the original file's extension.

```
save_path = os.path.join(save_directory, f"{title}{os.path.splitext(image_upload.name)[1]}")
```

This change is a good practice to make sure your saved files stay true to their original types.

Comment: I want to ask about the action tag to be more sure, does this action tag work in a way that when the user sends a request, the form tag with the action will check whether the request can be executed, if yes, a response will be sent, is that true? @YashashriPawar

Comment: @Newbie Programmer  yes... The `action` attribute in a `form tag` tells the browser where to send the form data when submitted. It's like providing an address for the data. If everything goes well, the server at that address processes the data and sends a response back to the user.